# Springboot Quartz: Build two schedulers (local and clustered)

Tags: spring-boot, quartz-scheduler, quartz

It's not clear to me which is the place where I need to set my scheduler properties.

I need to configure two schedulers:

- local
- clustered

How can I set a properties for my local and another properties for my clustered schedulers?

```
spring:
  datasource:
    ...
  quartz:
    job-store-type: jdbc
    properties:
      org.quartz.jobStore.isClustered: true
      org.quartz.scheduler.instanceId: AUTO
```

Answer (score 0):

To run only one instance of the job you have to have an annotation @DisallowConcurrentExecution on Job class before creating JobDetail. In this case JobDetail will be mark as Is_clustered in DB. Otherwise if you create JobDetail before adding an annotation then JobDetail stay nonClustered. So I see a solution in separating Jobs and marking them with annotation while using JDBC jobs storing.